# Reduction to a single function in tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsx

> ```
> loadPageItems: ((page: number) => Promise<void>)
> ```

```
const loadCustomers = useCallback(
       async (pageNumber?: number): Promise<void> => {
        loadCustomerItems (pageNumber)
    }
    
    const loadMarkets= useCallback(
       async (pageNumber?: number): Promise<void> => {
        loadMarketItems(pageNumber, selectedCustomer)
    } 

       <Table loadPageItems={loadCustomers } />
       <Table loadPageItems={loadMarkets} />
```

Hello guys, I have no problem with the above use but when I single out these functions with the name `loadPageItems` page is continuously returning 1 and I can't get the correct result. What could be the problem with my usage below?

```
const loadPageItems = useCallback(
       async (pageNumber?: number, customer?: Customer): Promise<void> => {
        customer ? loadMarketItems(pageNumber, customer) : loadCustomerItems (pageNumber)
    }


   <Table loadPageItems={() => loadPageItems()} />
   <Table loadPageItems={() => loadPageItems(undefined, selectedCustomer)} />
```

Comment: Are you missing the pageNumber argument from loadPageItems?

Comment: I don't send it in the code above, but it works. I want to know what is the technical difference